# Edit internal saved PDF-File with an external PDF-Viewer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

We're trying to open a pdf file, that is saved in our applications internal file storage, via an intent with a pdf-editor. We want to edit that file with the editor and save it back to the internal storage location, but that doesn't work.

We open the file with that code block:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.example.DetailView.provider", file);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The file is opened in the editor, but when we try to save the changes, we get prompted for a new file location. We also tried Intent.ACTION_EDIT, but with no success as well.

Has anybody an idea, what to change, so the pdf editor is able to write back to the original location?

Comment: Choose a different pdf editor app.

Comment: We tried several different pdf editor apps, but always the same result. Du you know one, which is capable of doing that?

Comment: No, sorry, no..